# Good graphic TimeSpan representation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, plugins, timespan

I have a `TimeSpan` where i save my timing records (such as a period between two dates) and i want to represent them with a good graphic. Is there any way to set a timing to represent using `TimeCircles`? I know that this plugins works like a timer from a specific date until now, but can i stop the timer while representing my `TimeSpan` value? If there is not, is there any other plugin to represent with a cool graphic my `TimeSpan`?

**CODE:**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
        <div class="ibox-title">Tempo di gestione minimo</div>
        <div class="ibox-content">
            <h2>
                Giorni: @Model.MinDate.Days<br />
                Ore: @Model.MinDate.Hours<br />
                Minuti: @Model.MinDate.Minutes<br />
                Secondi: @Model.MinDate.Seconds
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
        <div class="ibox-title">Tempo di gestione medio</div>
        <div class="ibox-content">
            <h2>
                Giorni: @Model.AvgDate.Days<br />
                Ore: @Model.AvgDate.Hours<br />
                Minuti: @Model.AvgDate.Minutes<br />
                Secondi: @Model.AvgDate.Seconds
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
        <div class="ibox-title">Tempo di gestione massimo</div>
        <div class="ibox-content">
            <h2>
                Giorni: @Model.MaxDate.Days<br />
                Ore: @Model.MaxDate.Hours<br />
                Minuti: @Model.MaxDate.Minutes<br />
                Secondi: @Model.MaxDate.Seconds
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a pic of my Time values 
[image]

Thanks in advance, and also sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display a static the time using [TimeCircles](http://git.wimbarelds.nl/TimeCircles/readme.php).

If you convert your timespan to seconds:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // ... retrieve your timespan here ...
    var time = new TimeSpan(1,2,3);
    var seconds = time.TotalSeconds;

    var responseModel = new MyViewModel
    {
        TimeInSeconds = seconds;
    };

    return View(responseModel);
}
```

Then in your page, initialize the plugin in a stopped state, this appears to work and displays the time nicely in Days, Hours, Mins, seconds...

```
@model MyViewModel

<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timecircles/1.5.3/TimeCircles.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timecircles/1.5.3/TimeCircles.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // Start the timer in a stopped state and it will remain static
        $(".example").TimeCircles({ "width": 100 }).stop();
    });
    </script>

    <div class="example" data-timer="@Model.TimeInSeconds" style="width:400"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Glad to have helped :o)